# Override of DrawCell from TCustomGrid > why protected?

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-10.2-tokyo

I am studying inheritance of a class to override a `DrawCell()` method. I refer the following page at docwiki.embarcadero.com:

[Changing Initial Values](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Changing_Initial_Values)

In the above C++ code, the `DrawCell()` method is defined as `protected`. I do not fully understand the class inheritance but I wonder why that is `protected`, not `private`, or so.

Is this determined by C++Builder or C++ (to use override feature of C++ in C++Builder)?

Comment: `DrawCell()` is `virtual` and `protected` in `TCustomGrid`, so descendant classes (like `TSampleCalendar`) can override it, without exposing it as `public` for the whole world to access. If it were `private`, descendants could not reach it to override it. But they can reach it when it is `protected`. It is customary to preserve the same visibility when overriding a method, unless there is a compelling reason to change it. This is simply how polymorphism works in C++ in general, it is not specific to C++Builder.

Comment: I appreciate your reply. My understanding about inheritance was lacking.